# How can i reduce the number of symbols in my Haskell DLL? ("export ordinal too large")

Tags: haskell, dll, ghc

I'm building a DLL in Haskell for use on both macOS and Windows and am having a problem with the latter. Specifically, the number of symbols in the DLL becomes too great (“export ordinal too large”):

```
Linking mydll.dll ...
C://Users//bjorn//AppData//Local//Programs//stack//i386-windows//ghc-8.6.5//mingw//bin/ld.exe: Error: export ordinal too large: 73799
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

This is closely related to the problem described at https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/windows-dynamic-linking, which describes the ordinal limit I am running into:

> The primary reason for this is a limitation in the `PE` specification which uses for the `ordinal` value (a unique number/index associated with a exported symbol) a 16bit int. Which limits the amount of symbols we can export to `2^16-1 (~65k)` symbols.

Unfortunately I lack the expertise of @Phyx and am a bit stumped as how to solve/work around the problem for my case.

## Investigation

By some trial an error I replaced some code using attoparsec with `undefined` which from what I understand prevented attoparsec (and probably some of its dependencies) from being linked in. This brought the number of symbols down to 60232 (counted using `nm -g mydll.dll | wc -l`). This is not to say that attoparsec is the problem, but just to provide an example of how the DLL grows with dependencies.

### Symbols

The end-user API for the DLL consists of a number of [FFI](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface) `foreign export ccall` functions. As an example there is the function/action `logStarted` (`foreign export ccall logStarted :: IO ()`). Grepping for `logStarted` in the output of `nm -g` I find:

```
6b6910d0 D _FFI_logStarted_closure
6af817fc T _FFI_logStarted_info
6b6910d8 D _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted_closure
6af81810 T _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted_info
6b6910c0 D _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted1_closure
6af817c8 T _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted1_info
6b6910b0 D _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted2_closure
6af81780 T _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted2_info
6b76509e R _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted3_bytes
6b691098 D _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted4_closure
6af816d8 T _FFI_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCFFIZZClogStarted4_info
6af87522 T _logStarted
```

This is a lot of symbols when the only one I need is `_logStarted`. Similarly several symbols are defined for each haskell functions linked into the DLL (regardless of what package they are from and the vast majority which are of course not part of the end-user API).

## What have I tried

1. Passing `--discard-all` to `ld` (with `ld-options: -Wl,--discard-all`) reduces the number of symbols by about 100, so it isn't very useful.
2. Using the `--retain-symbols-file=api.txt` option of `ld` (mentioned in https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/windows-dynamic-linking). This is not a very attractive solution in the first place since I would have to maintain `api.txt` to be consistent with my FFI exports.Anyway, it does not work since it (appears to) assemble the DLL first and afterwards strip symbols. The assembling step still fails. (Similar results when trying `--strip-all`.)

## Thoughts

Can I somehow ask `ghc` to be more restrictive in what symbols to export? In the end all I want exported is the FFI exports

Could the [`gen-dll`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/utils/gen-dll/Main.hs) tool used for building GHC DLLs help? It seems it could but I am not sure what arguments are appropriate.

### Relevant, maybe?

(Is the solution staring me in the face?)

- https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/windows-dynamic-linking
- https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/utils/gen-dll/Main.hs
- https://phabricator.haskell.org/D3883
- https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/5987
- https://github.com/Mistuke/ghc/pull/5

## Note on current build process

I'm building the DLL with stack and a [`foreign-library`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#foreign-libraries) stanza in the cabal file. However, I get the same results when compiling by hand (using, e.g., `ghc -o mydll.dll -shared -static [files]`). If necessary (e.g. to integrate `gen-dll` in the flow) I  will change to a hand-rolled build script.

Right now I am building on 32-bit Windows, but intend to produce a 64-bit version of the DLL too.